# Powershell - unknown duplicate output from switch statement

Tags: powershell

I'm having issue to output a result, the condition match however it display duplicate entry. Not sure did I missed any thing. Can any kind soul advise on this. thank you :)

file.txt content

```
aaa new-model
aaa local authentication attempts max-fail 3
!
aaa group server radius helloworld
 server-private XX.XX.10.10 auth-port 1812 acct-port 1813 key 7 123F123412345D5678
 ip radius source-interface Vlan123
!
aaa session-id common
!
```

my script Checking.ps1

```
$file = "C:\file.txt"
$results = switch -File $file -Regex {
"aaa group server radius helloworld" {$entry = [PSCustomObject]@{
aaa_group_server_radius_helloworld = $_;
server_private_x_x_10_10 = $false;
server_private_x_x_20_20 = $false;
ip_radius_source_interface = $false;}}
"server-private XX.XX.10.10 auth-port 1812 acct-port 1813 key .*"   {$entry.server_private_x_x_10_10 = $true}
"server-private XX.XX.20.20 auth-port 1812 acct-port 1813 key .*"   {$entry.server_private_x_x_20_20 = $true}
"ip radius source-interface.*"  {$entry.ip_radius_source_interface = $true}
"!" {$entry}

$results | ? {($_.server_private_x_x_10_10 -eq $false) -or
($_.server_private_x_x_20_20 -eq $false) -or
($_.ip_radius_source_interface -eq $false) 
} | Format-List
```

Output from my script:

```
aaa_group_server_radius_helloworld : aaa group server radius helloworld
server_private_x_x_10_10           : True
server_private_x_x_20_20           : False
ip_radius_source_interface         : True

aaa_group_server_radius_helloworld : aaa group server radius helloworld
server_private_x_x_10_10           : True
server_private_x_x_20_20           : False
ip_radius_source_interface         : True
```

Expected Output just need to display matching result without duplicate:

```
aaa_group_server_radius_helloworld : aaa group server radius helloworld
server_private_x_x_10_10           : True
server_private_x_x_20_20           : False
ip_radius_source_interface         : True
```

Answer (score 0):

`"!" {$entry}` and there are three `!` in your input file. The first one, `$entry` is blank, the second two both output the same entry.

Comment: Hi TessellatingHeckler, can you advise how come I make it just match those string between from starting "aaa group server radius helloworld" and end at "!" with the above expected output. Thanks